# Java, Search for a long in the binary file input

Tags: java, buffer

```
Public static void main(String[] args) {
  File inFile = null;
  if (0 < args.length) {
      inFile = new File(args[0]);
  }

    BufferedInputStream bStream = null;

    try {

        int read;
        bStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFile));

        while ((read = bStream.read()) > 0) {
            getMarker(read, bStream);
            System.out.println(read);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    finally {
        try {
            if (bStream != null)bStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static void getMarker(int read, BufferedInputStream bStream) {

}
```

I want to find the long 1234567890 in the bufferedInputStream.  Am I able to search the bufferedInputStream for a long type?  (I'm not sure whether I need 'read' as a parameter.  I doubt it, I may remove that).  How do I search a bufferedInputStream?

Comment: A `long` is 8 bytes in size. Is your file 8-byte aligned?

Comment: What is more, depending on whether the longs in your file are written as little endian or big endian, its binary representation differs. So, what is what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number is 8 byte aligned and big endian, you can use DataInputStream.

If not I suggest memory mapping the file and using ByteBuffer.order to change the order to little endian.  This will allow you to access the file in any manner you wish.